# Exception safety of std::function

Tags: c++, function, exception, c++11, language-lawyer

I tried without success to find if this code could throw an exception :

```
std::function<void(void)>f=[]{};
```

According to the standard, the copy or move constructor of std::function are not noexcept. But I guess the lack of the noexcept keyword is due to the fact that std::function also wrap user defined functor object whose copy or move constructors could throw.

In my case an exception seems very unlikely but is it possible at all ?

Comment: This case specifically can't throw an exception, as far as I'm aware (well, except out-of-memory exceptions, but when you get those, you're in bigger trouble anyways).

Comment: @Xeo: *flag as not a comment*

Comment: Since `std::function` uses internal magic like type erasure, I think it *always* has to deal with the possibility of allocation failures. I guess you could implement a "small member optimization" for type erasure, but that might be extreme.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, the standard recommends a small buffer optimization atleast the size of member-function-pointer + `void*` (for the object pointer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In my case an exception seems very unlikely but is it possible at all ?

In principle, yes. `std::function` will have to allocate memory to store the callable object it's initialised with, and if that memory is allocated dynamically then there's the possibility of failure.

In practice, in your case, no. In the words of a note in the specification, "Implementations are encouraged to avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for small callable objects". A lambda with no captures is convertible to a function pointer, which is about as small as a callable object gets; so a good implementation should certainly store that without dynamic allocation. And of course, copying a pointer can't throw either.

Larger objects (including lambdas with many captures) will need dynamic allocation, and need to copy their captured objects or other state, and so can't offer a no-throw guarantee.

Comment: In this case, an allocation is probably required because of type erasure in std::function. In that case this constructor can throw. Also, in the even more general case, if the lambda captured something you would have the possibility of exceptions in the copy constructors.

Comment: I'd wager that an empty lambda object is smaller than a function pointer. :P Also, why would you store a lambda as a function pointer, specifically special-casing empty lambdas from all other function objects?

Comment: @Xeo: Because I didn't think too hard about exactly how to implement `std::function` when I answered the question. Perhaps storing the lambda directly would be more efficient that converting it to a function pointer, but that doesn't change my point that it's "small".

Comment: @Stewart: A small callable object can (and should, according to that standard quote) be stored in an internal buffer within the `function` object to avoid dynamic allocation. Indeed, more generally, a lambda with many captures could get too large for that; but I'm asking this question which begins "in my case".

Comment: @Mike - my bad. I didn't read your answer carefully enough. I still think it is a worthwhile point to call out though, since most other people won't read your answer carefully enough and will say that "stack overflow says this line can't throw", which in general isn't true.